# AngularJS - calculate value for each field

Tags: angularjs

I have list of fields(todos) with button on their left. I want to click on one of the buttons so it calculate the value for this specific field.

What I'm getting is that clicking on specific button calculate and show the same result for all the fields

this is what I wrote :

```
<h1 ng-show="myVar">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="todo in todos">
      <button ng-show="!editing[$index]" ng-click="edit($index)">click</button>
      <h2> Result is:{{result}}</h2>
      {{todo.name}}
    </li>
  </ul>
  </h1>
```

and the controller

```
      $scope.edit = function(index){

        var todo = $scope.todos[index];
        var counter = 0;
        angular.forEach($scope.todos,function(value,index){
            if (todo.topic == 'important')
            {counter = counter+1;}

        })
        $scope.result =  counter;
      }
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically `result` variable of `scope` you have used for binding is not the same scope variable which has been defined inside controller scope.

Because `ng-repeat` does work in quite a different way, when it render a DOM by looping through provided collection(here its `todos`), it creates a new scope for each iteration which is prototypically inherited from it parent scope.

Do use `Dot Rule` while defining model, so that it would follow prototypal inheritance,

```
$scope.model = {};

//then use 
$scope.model.result = result;
```

**HTML**

```
<h2> Result is:{{model.result}}</h2>
```

Other way around to sort this issue out would be using `controllerAs` approach while defining controller, but in that case you need to get read of `$scope` & should replace it with `this` context of controller function.

Comment: This was very helpful! Now it calculates the correct result. 
The only thing is that I see the result next to all the fields. How can I change it so the result will be shown only for the specific field and not for everyone?

Comment: @A.Sh then do pass that specific object to edit method like `ng-click="edit(todo)"` and add result property to `todo` object, so that will make individual result value by having `todo.result`.

Comment: todo is a field from db... do you mean to add result property to the db? Cause I don't want to change the db. Can I do it differently?

Comment: Isn't it more html thing to handle? I just don't know how to show the result just for the specific button and not for all

Comment: @A.Sh I can't give a good thought on it unless you explain whole scenario.. please do explain..

Comment: Sorry. I mean I just want a list
<click>todo1
<click>todo2...
And when I click on the first button- It will show the result only for todo1. If i click the second button i get the result for todo2 etc..

Comment: So then you should add that property in each of record, in that way it would solve your problem. No need to persist in db. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You use the same `index` variable name as a function input parameter - `function(index)` and in forEach loop `,function(value,index){` - and  it gets overwritten.

```
//here
$scope.edit = function(index){

  var todo = $scope.todos[index];
  var counter = 0;
//and here
  angular.forEach($scope.todos,function(value,index){
```

Comment: but I call this function for every button so the index in `$scope.edit = function(index){` should change every time, no?